# Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration - SSL and Kerberos Integration?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to see if it is worthwhile to switch from regular streaming to structured.  Does Spark 2.1.x structured streaming support consuming from secured Kafka (SSL_SASL).  Meaning Kerberos and SLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark Streaming and Structured Streaming use the same Kafka client. The configuration for secured Kafka is same.